# Maven throws nullpointer exception

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Good day,

I have built a project using maven. Throughout this project, I have concluded that one more dependency has to be added for a particular module. I have added this dependency in it's pom file and when I have tried to rebuild the project using maven, a null pointer was thrown.

Pom files before:

(child pom:)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

(main pom:)

```
    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.solveit.crm.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>crm-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency> //this dependency is for another module, it was
                        declared at the start of the project


    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Pom files now(which cause nullpointer):

(child pom:)

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.solveit.crm.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>crm-data</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

(main pom:)

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.solveit.crm.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>crm-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.solveit.crm.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>crm-data</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Why does maven throw null pointer exception? I am confused right now.

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.NullPointerEx
ception
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:167)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:270)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        ... 11 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/InternalErrorE
xception
```

In eclipse I get:

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference: Edge between 'Vertex{label='com.solveit.crm.data:crm-data:1'}' and 'Vertex{label='com.solveit.crm.core:crm-core:1'}' introduces to cycle in the graph com.solveit.crm.core:crm-core:1 --> com.solveit.crm.data:crm-data:1 --> com.solveit.crm.core:crm-core:1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectCycleException
```

Thank you

Comment: Try maven clean install command under that same project directory using the command window instead of Eclipse.

Comment: Jay, I have used cmd instead of Eclipse for this

Comment: I have tried building this project in eclipse now, and I get a different error. I have edited and added the eclipse error above

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I avoid a dependency cycle with one edge being a test dependency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034513/can-i-avoid-a-dependency-cycle-with-one-edge-being-a-test-dependency)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have a cyclic reference of dependencies.

It looks like your crm-core project has crm-data in its dependencies and the crm-data project has crm-core in its dependencies.

Maven can't compile such a case.

Comment: how should I deal in this case? How can I make two modules dependent on each other?

Comment: You can move common classes/resources to a third independent module and make the two existing modules depend on this common module.

Comment: According to me, you can't. Maybe you can think of another conception for your project. You can use a common module as ssssteffff proposed.

Comment: Hmm, okay... Thank you guyis, I will keep that in mind next time. Cheers

Comment: I don't think that Maven crashing with a NullPointerException is the best way to explain the cyclic dependency.

Comment: If you are using eclipse m2e plugin, it will give you a better error message hinting there is a cyclical dependency.